# embed small map (cartopy) on matplotlib figure

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, cartopy

```py
# imports
from collections import namedtuple
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import shapely
import cartopy
```

## The data that I have looks like this.

I have a region of interest (defined here as `all_region`). I have an `xr.DataArray` which contains my variable.
What I want to do it to select one PIXEL (lat,lon pair) and to plot a small map in the corner of the lineplot showing here that pixel is located.

```py
Region = namedtuple('Region',field_names=['region_name','lonmin','lonmax','latmin','latmax'])
all_region = Region(
    region_name="all_region",
    lonmin = 32.6,
    lonmax = 51.8,
    latmin = -5.0,
    latmax = 15.2,
)

data = np.random.normal(0,1,(12, 414, 395))
lats = np.linspace(-4.909738, 15.155708, 414)
lons = np.linspace(32.605801, 51.794488, 395)
months = np.arange(1,13)
da = xr.DataArray(data, coords=[months, lats, lons], dims=['month','lat','lon'])
```

## These are the functions that I need to fix to work with inset axes.

I have these functions which plot my timeseries from the xarray object, and also the location of the lat,lon point.

```py
def plot_location(region):
    """ use cartopy to plot the region (defined as a namedtuple object)
    """
    lonmin,lonmax,latmin,latmax = region.lonmin,region.lonmax,region.latmin,region.latmax
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())
    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE)
    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle=':')
    ax.set_extent([lonmin, lonmax, latmin, latmax])

    return fig, ax


def select_pixel(ds, loc):
    """ (lat,lon) """
    return ds.sel(lat=loc[1],lon=loc[0],method='nearest')


def turn_tuple_to_point(loc):
    """ (lat,lon) """
    from shapely.geometry.point import Point
    point = Point(loc[1], loc[0])
    return point


def add_point_location_to_map(point, ax, color=(0,0,0,1), **kwargs):
    """ """
    ax.scatter(point.x,
           point.y,
           transform=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree(),
           c=[color],
           **kwargs)
    return
```

## Here I do the plotting

```
# choose a lat lon location that want to plot
loc = (2.407,38.1)

# 1. plot the TIME SERIES FOR THE POINT
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
pixel_da = select_pixel(da, loc)
pixel_da.plot.line(ax=ax, marker='o')

# 2. plot the LOCATION for the point
fig,ax = plot_location(all_region)
point = turn_tuple_to_point(loc)
add_point_location_to_map(point, ax)
```

[image: Plot 1]

[image: Plot 2]

## I have my function for plotting a region, but I want to put this on an axis in the corner of my figure! Like this:

[image: Ideal output]

How would I go about doing this? I have had a look at the [`inset_locator` method](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/inset_locator_demo.html) but as far as I can tell the `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.parasite_axes.AxesHostAxes` has no means of assigning a projection, which is required for cartopy.

```py
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes

proj=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree
axins = inset_axes(ax, width="20%", height="20%", loc=2, projection=proj)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-162-9b5fd4f34c3e> in <module>
----> 1 axins = inset_axes(ax, width="20%", height="20%", loc=2, projection=proj)

TypeError: inset_axes() got an unexpected keyword argument 'projection'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.inset_axes` does not have a `projection` keyword. It only provides an `axes_class` argument. Now one might be tempted to provide the `cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes` directly to that argument, yet this would be missing the actual projection in use. So in addition one needs to set the projection via the `axes_kwargs` argument.

```
inset_axes(...,  axes_class=cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes, 
                 axes_kwargs=dict(map_projection=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree()))
```

Complete example:

```
import cartopy
import cartopy.mpl.geoaxes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([4,5,3,1,2])


axins = inset_axes(ax, width="40%", height="40%", loc="upper right", 
                   axes_class=cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes, 
                   axes_kwargs=dict(map_projection=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree()))
axins.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! just having a quick play with both answers now

Answer (score 1):

I don't have `cartopy` installed to test it directly, but I believe you can circumvent the problem by creating your inset Axes by hand directly, [using `fig.add_axes()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html?highlight=add_axes#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes). If you want to specify its position relative to the main axes, you can easily calculate the `rect` parameter using the info returned by the main axes `get_position()`.

For example:

```
pad = 0.05
w = 0.4
h = 0.25

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
a = ax.get_position()
ax2 = fig.add_axes([a.x1-(w+pad)*a.width,a.y1-(h+pad)*a.height,w*a.width,h*a.height], projection="hammer")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! just having an experiment with both answers now

Comment: This also works! I don't quite know how which to select but both are great answers!