# embed small map (cartopy) on another cartopy map

Tags: python, matplotlib, maps, cartopy

I have created this map with cartopy:
[image] with code:

```
import matplotlib.image as image
import cartopy.mpl.geoaxes

use_proj = ccrs.Mercator()
use_proj._threshold /= 20.

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1,subplot_kw={'projection': use_proj}, figsize=(7,7), gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0.2, 'hspace': 0.2})
ax1.set_extent([-50.0, 45.0, 30.0, 70.0])
ax1.coastlines('50m', color='black')
ax1.plot([-19, 40, 40, -19, -19], [35, 35, 73, 73, 35],
         color='blue', linewidth=2.5,
         transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), label='Pressure')


plt.scatter(x=12.5683, y=55.6761,
            color="red",
            s=12,
            alpha=0.9,
            transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),label='Temperature') ## Important
```

and I would like to add in the top right another plot:[image]

that I created with the code:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1,subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.Mercator()}, figsize=(7,7), gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0.2, 'hspace': 0.2})
ax1.set_extent([10, 15, 54, 57])
ax1.coastlines('10m', color='black')
plt.scatter(x=df1.longitude, y=df1.latitude,
            color="dodgerblue",
            s=12,
            alpha=0.9,
            transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()) ## Important
```

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55385515/embed-small-map-cartopy-on-matplotlib-figure